# Android actionbar using icon form navigation

Tags: android, android-actionbar

According to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html --> Using the App Icon for Navigation

It says all I have to do is to add the given coding so that the app icon in the upper left corner becomes a "button" to navigate home. When I click on the icon the onOptionsItemSelected method is not called at all. What else do I have to do? It is called whenever I select an entry from the overflow area. Do I need to create a menu entry for this is any special way? I understood it that way that it comes out of the box and I only add case android.R.id.home: to my switch statement.

Comment: Have you tried adding `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`?

Comment: thanks this solved the question I must have missed that somehow.